# What is $(n,\frac{|G|}{n})$? Is that the gcd of these two?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if for every divisor $n$ of $|G|$ such that $(n,\frac{|G|}{n})=1$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

---

What is $(n,\frac{|G|}{n})$? Is that the gcd of these two?

Comment: Seems so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(n,m)$ is the greatest common divisor of $m,n$ and that theorem is true when we take that interpretation.

Comment: Thanks. Normally we write gcd(n,m), so I wasn't sure

Comment: Also just quickly, the correct interpretation of this theorem is that if we have $|G|=16$ we find divisors $1,2,4,8$ and then we get $(8,2)=2,(4,4)=4,(2,8)=2,(1,16)=1$, and since the trivial subgroup is in $G$, $G$ is solvable?

(Which is consistent with the fact that $|G|=16$ is cyclic I believe)

Comment: When $|G|=16$ it basically tells us a group of order $16$ is solvable if and only if it has subgroups of order $16$ and $1$. Which is of course true of any group of order $16$. This is in fact true (every group of order $16$ is solvable). More generally every $p$-group is solvable.